# onsubmit(return test();) doesn't return false;

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onsubmit

I have the following problem. I have the following form

```
<form  name="asianCalculator" action="" id="asianCalculator" onsubmit="return testfunction(this.form);">
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">
            Επιλογή Handicap
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">                            

          <div class="asian_selector_big">                                      
          <select class="selectbox_big" name="handicap" id="handicap">
                    <option value="-4.00">-4.00</option>
                    <option value="-3.75">-3.75 (-3.5, -4.0)</option>
                    <option value="-3.50">-3.50</option>
                    <option value="-3.25">-3.25 (-3.0, -3.5)</option>
                    <option value="-3.00">-3.00</option>
                    <option value="-2.75">-2.75 (-2.5, -3.0)</option>
                    <option value="-2.50">-2.50</option>
                    <option value="-2.25">-2.25 (-2.0, -2.5)</option>
                    <option value="-2.00">-2.00</option>
                    <option value="-1.75">-1.75 (-1.5, -2.0)</option>
                    <option value="-1.50">-1.50</option>
                    <option value="-1.25">-1.25 (-1.0, -1.5)</option>
                    <option value="-1.00">-1.00</option>
                    <option value="-0.75">-0.75 (-0.5, -1.0)</option>
                    <option value="-0.50">-0.50</option>
                    <option value="-0.25">-0.25 (0.0, -0.5)</option>
                    <option value="0.00" selected="selected">0.0 (level)</option>
                    <option value="0.25">+0.25 (0.0, +0.5)</option>
                    <option value="0.50">+0.50</option>
                    <option value="0.75">+0.75 (+0.5, +1.0)</option>
                    <option value="1.00">+1.00</option>
                    <option value="1.25">+1.25 (+1.0, +1.5)</option>
                    <option value="1.50">+1.50</option>
                    <option value="1.75">+1.75 (+1.5, +2.0)</option>
                    <option value="2.00">+2.00</option>
                    <option value="2.25">+2.25 (+2.0, +2.5)</option>
                    <option value="2.50">+2.50</option>
                    <option value="2.75">+2.75 (+2.5, +3.0)</option>
                    <option value="3.00">+3.00</option>
                    <option value="3.25">+3.25 (+3.0, +3.5)</option>
                    <option value="3.50">+3.50</option>
                    <option value="3.75">+3.75 (+3.5, +4.0)</option>
                    <option value="4.00">+4.00</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">
            Επιλλογή ομάδας
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">
            <div class="asian_selector_big">
                <select class="selectbox_big" name="selection" id="selection">
                    <option value="h">Γηπεδούχος</option>
                    <option value="a">Φιλοξενούμενη</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">
            <label for="odds">
                Απόδοση σημείου
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">
            <input class="asian_input" name="odds" type="text" id="odds" value="1.91" />
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div>    
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">
            <label for="wager">
                Ποντάρισμα
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">
            <input class="asian_input" name="wager" type="text" id="wager" value="100" />
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div> 
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">
            Επιλογή κέρδους
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">
            <div class="asian_selector_big">
                <select  class="selectbox_big" name="calcOption" id="calcOption">
                    <option value="s" selected="selected" onclick="toggleSpecificOptions(true)">Αποτέλεσμα</option>
                    <option value="a" onclick="toggleSpecificOptions(false)">Γενικά</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div>
    <div id="form_row_hide">
        <div class="form_label">
            Αποτέλεσμα
        </div>
        <div class="form_input">
            <div class="asian_selector_small">
                <select class="selectbox_small" name="homeScore" id="homeScore">
                    <option selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="versus">-</div> 
            <div class="asian_selector_small">
                <select class="selectbox_small" name="awayScore" id="awayScore">
                    <option selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                           
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />   
</form>
```

I want to validate the 2 input fields so I used the livevalidation found here http://livevalidation.com/ to get rid of those ugly "alerts".

My problem now is that I want to do some calculations in `testfunction()` and I don't want the form to be submitted. I could have used a `type="button"` instead of "submit" but that way the livevalidation won't work.

So when I type something like:

```
function testfunction (myform) {

var odds = myform.odds.value;
var handicap = myform.handicap.options[myform.handicap.selectedIndex].value;
    //much more code here
    return false; }
```

It ignores the return false and the form is submitted. If I don't have anything that gets the input from the form it works fine. So how can I get the input on submit and return false so the form wont be submitted?

Comment: try a couple of tests.. first write`OnSubmit=return false`.. if that works, put several `alert()` in ur javascript function .. and test whether it runs the function.. but ur function seems that u r returning `false` everytime.. may b coz it is a sample code. if u r using `if-else` to return the value, `alert()` return value before i t returns..

Comment: It doesn't return false; It gets an error and by default it returns true. The error is that myform is undefiend .If i replace the myform with document.asianCalculator it works. But i can't see why

Comment: in the onsubmit event on the form you should pass to the function just this not this.form

Comment: I can't believe i spent 3 hours try to figure this out.I had the event on a button before i use the livevalidator and handle or the errors with alerts. Then i copy paste the code change the onclick to onsubmit but didnt change the this .... Thanks a lot for opening my eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you can do is

```
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="return (testfunction ('yourform'));" />
```

it will return the return ( false ) of the function while calling it.